# how can i make a simple store program

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, joptionpane

I'm so confused right now because I don't know how I can add the items and the quantity of the items that's in a drop down list. Can someone help me even with just an idea how to do it? Thank you in advance. Let me know if you need to know something because I can't explain very well. Thank you again.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //menu list

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Username",
                "Welcome to our computerized store!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        String[] items = {"Pork barbeque- 25",
                "\nGrilled jumbo hotdog- 10",
                "\nFried Rice- 10"};
        String choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome " + username +
                "\nWhat is your order?", "Choose your order below!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, items, items[0]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You choose " + choice, "Your request", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        String pieces = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Below is the discount depending on how much you can avail:" +
                "\n(please type how many pieces you can avail!)" +
                "\n*100 pieces, 10%" +
                "\n*300 pieces, 15%" +
                "\n*500 pieces, 20%" +
                "\n*1000 pieces, 50%" +
                "\n*NO discount for orders 99 below", "How many pieces can you avail?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You avail " + pieces + " pcs.");
        
        //ARGHHH I DONT KNOW HOW TO ADD THEM
```

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the discounted price? If the user wants 100 hotdogs then she needs to pay 900, correct?

Comment: the user will choose what is her order, then she will type how many orders, then if that order is in the discounted promo she will have a discount (depends on the promo is the discount), and it will calculated the total price. i hope i explain it im bad in english sorry.

Comment: Would you consider making your program a GUI? Refer to [Java 8 Client Technologies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm). In other words use either _Swing_ or JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is a real quick-and-dirty. It gets your desired result but I believe that your program is more suitable as a GUI application. `JOptionPane` is not the best way to get data from the user.

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //menu list

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                      "Enter Username",
                                                      "Welcome to our computerized store!",
                                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        String[] items = {"Pork barbeque- 25",
                          "\nGrilled jumbo hotdog- 10",
                          "\nFried Rice- 10"};
        String choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                             "Welcome " + username + "\nWhat is your order?",
                                                             "Choose your order below!",
                                                             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                                                             null,
                                                             items,
                                                             items[0]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                      "You choose " + choice,
                                      "Your request",
                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        String pieces = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                    "Below is the discount depending on how much you can avail:" +
                                                          "\n(please type how many pieces you can avail!)" +
                                                          "\n*100 pieces, 10%" +
                                                          "\n*300 pieces, 15%" +
                                                          "\n*500 pieces, 20%" +
                                                          "\n*1000 pieces, 50%" +
                                                          "\n*NO discount for orders 99 below",
                                                    "How many pieces can you avail?",
                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You avail " + pieces + " pcs.");
        String cost = choice.substring(choice.length() - 2);
        int price = Integer.parseInt(cost);
        int units = Integer.parseInt(pieces);
        double discount;
        if (units >= 1000) {
            discount = 0.5d;
        }
        else if (units >= 500) {
            discount = 0.8d;
        }
        else if (units >= 300) {
            discount = 0.85d;
        }
        else if (units >= 100) {
            discount = 0.9d;
        }
        else {
            discount = 1.0d;
        }
        double payable = price * units * discount;
        System.out.printf("You owe %.2f%n", payable);
    }
}
```

Comment: it helps so much thank you i already fix the problem thank you again:>